# Dagger reference module from child class at runtime

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, android-architecture

I'm having android libraries LBase, L1, L2 with dependency like LBase->L1 and LBase -> L2. And android Apps A1 built from L1 and A2 built from L2

In LBase

```
public interface iA {

}

public A implements iA {

}

@Component(modules = ModuleBase.class)
public interface BaseComponent {
    iA getA()
}

@Module
public class ModuleBase.class {
   @Provides
   public iA createA() {
     return new A();
   } 

}
```

In L1

```
public class A1 implements iA {

}

@Module
public class ModuleL1 extends ModuleBase {
   @Provides
   public iA createA() {
     return new A1();
   } 
}
```

In L2

```
public class A2 implements iA {

}

@Module
public class ModuleL2 extends ModuleBase {
   @Provides
   public iA createA() {
     return new A2();
   } 
}
```

It seems ModuleBase.class cannot be a interface or abstract class so I am looking for help to achieve the same.

Basically what I am looking to do is provide implmentation module in LBase (instead of ModuleBase.class) at run time to either "ModuleL1.class" or "ModuleL2.class" in A1 or A2 respectively.

Comment: Can you please explain what you try to achieve in doing that? What do you mean by `replace "ModuleBase.class"`? You can't change the annotations at runtime! Especially as all of this is compiled

Comment: @Eselfar : I am basically trying to get the implementation at run time based on which library is compiled through dagger